# Suggestion for new 'hold' reason

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

We seem to close/hold an awful lot of questions that would be easily answered if the OP were to provide or clarify one or two minor details. However the VTC's don't indicate that, so I propose we add a new one that says something like:

> More information required

Yes there is often a comment asking for that info but the time window between those comments and the question getting closed is often very small, and because the close reasons given have often been "Off-topic" or "Unclear" I'm concerned that askers may be returning to the site after the comment asking for more information and then leaving again because the big yellow banner of doom is telling them that their question can't be answered here.

And while we have got the sort-of custom option of "I'm voting to close because.." which *could* be used for it I think fundamentally people aren't using that one much at all - it's much easier to just click one of the pre-made reasons and move on.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to make it even easier to vote to close than it already is.  With the high percentage of closes already, adding hundreds of canned reasons isn't useful.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think we need a new close reason - the "Unclear" close reason already includes questions that require more information.

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That says pretty clearly that the OP needs to supply information. Your concern that the yellow banner scares away new users may be valid, but that is true for being closed in general, regardless of close reason. Giving it a new name isn't going to change that.

However, we could still possibly improve on the current close reason to make it more clear (ironic, I know). Maybe instead of "Unclear what you are asking" the title is changed to "Requires more information". The updated text might then be (change in bold)

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking, **or specific information may be needed to provide an accurate answer**.

That being said, I think this close reason is StackExchange-wide, so I'm not sure we have much of a chance of fixing it.

Comment: I'd say that pretty specifically relates to supplying formation to make the question clear, and if (as is often the case) the situation is that they just need to provide a location then seeing "Unclear what you're asking" feels very disingenuous and needlessly hostile IMO.

Comment: @motosubatsu See my edit.

Comment: fair enough, that does make it clearer